# Is it possible to build a C standard library that is agnostic to the both the OS and compiler being used?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, standards, compatibility, libc

First off, I know that any such library would need to have at least *some* interface shimming to interact with system calls or board support packages or whatever (For example; `newlib` has a [limited and well defined interface](https://www.sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls) to the OS/BSP that doesn't assume intimate access to the OS). I can als see where there will be need for something similar for interacting with the compiler (e.g. details of some things left as "implementation defined" by the standard).

However, most libraries I've looked into end up being *way* more wedded to the OS and compiler than that. The OS assumptions seems to assume access to whatever parts they want from a specific OS environment and the compiler interactions practically in collusion with the compiler implementation it self.

So, the basic questions end up being:

1. Would it be possible (and practical) to implement a full C standard library that only has a *very limited and well defined* set of prerequisites and/or interface for being built by any compiler and run on any OS?
2. Do any such implementation exist? (I'm not asking for a recommendation of one to use, thought I would be interested in examples that I can make my own evaluations of.)
3. If either of the above answers is "no"; then why? What fundamentally makes it impossible or impractical? Or why hasn't anyone bothered?

---

### Background:

What I'm working on that has lead me to this rabbit hole is an attempt to make a fully versioned, fully hermetic build chain. The goal being that I should be able to build a project without *any* dependencies on the local environment (beyond access to the needs source control repo and say "a valid posix shell" or "[language-agnostic-build-tool-of-choice](https://bazel.build/) is installed and runs"). Given those dependencies, the build should do the exact same thing, with the same compiler and libraries, regardless of which versions of which compilers and libraries are or are not installed. Universal, repeatable, byte identical output is the target I'm wanting to move in the direction of.

Causing the compiler-of-choice to be run from a repo isn't too hard, but I've yet to have found a C standard library that "works right out of the box". They all seem to assume some magic undocumented interface between them and the compiler (e.g. `__gnuc_va_list`), or at best want to do some sort of config-probing of the hosting environment which would be something between useless and counterproductive for my goals.

This looks to be a bottomless rabbit hole that I'm reluctant to start down without first trying to locate alternatives.

Comment: Build in a container?

Comment: Well the V Lang programming language compiles itself on any platform with just a `git clone ...; cd ...; make` in under a second... so yeah, the answer is yes.

Comment: There's no way you can implement varargs.h without reaching into the compiler implementation for that platform. And without varargs.h, you cannot implement printf and friends. The general assumption is that at least part of the standard library -- that part which cannot be expressed in pure C -- is part of the implementation; i.e., definitely welded to the compiler. That logic could make compiler interop impossible, so it's not usually taken to an extreme and on many (but not all) platforms, the compiler provides (semi-)documented hooks to allow third parties to implement a standard library.

Comment: You'd also need low level access to the call stack for `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`, a way to get memory from the OS, file manipulation, a way to return exit status to the OS, signals, getting current time, probably some other stuff I'm forgetting.

Comment: Re OS stuff: newlib already seems to solve that bit with a list of about 20 functions so in theory other implementationa could as well. Re things like varargs: user code can use that as printf could be implemented via the same API so the question is how large is the list of things like that that would need to be provided? And would it be a responsible task to construct that small interface for a new compiler (as opposed to having the whole library wedded to a given compiler)?

Comment: @bcs: I think that's basically the architecture of most libraries. The Gnu C library, for example, has platform-independent code for most functions, although the build system will prefer to use the code optimised for the hardware platform (which, I suspect, is what most users would want).

Comment: @rici — `varargs.h`?  You mean `<stdarg.h>`, presumably, since `varargs.h` was never standardized per se.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but unfortunately comments are not editable. The principle is identical, though.

Comment: You have to design a mechanism to handle locales, etc.  That can be done in a way that is mostly O/S independent.  See P J Plauger [The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) 1992.  Yes, it is old; it deals with C90 and not the later standards.  But it has a lot of valuable information in it and it does largely deal with the issues you face.  Note that C11 or C18 support for `<threads.h>` will be problematic to do wholly independently of the O/S, over and above the other problem children (`<stdarg.h>` and `<setjmp.h>`, along with parts of `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`).

Comment: @rici while that may be true in theory; my attempts to construct a tool chain suggest that in practice it doesn't actually work that way: rather than defaulting to a "hook not defined" or the like it errors with errors about compiler specific things not being defined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The question isn't really can things be 100% OS independent, but rather can the context dependent stuff be limited to a manageable small set? A set that can be implemented without the collaboration of the compiler. So far, I haven't seen a suggestion that even threads, varargs and setjump/longjump prevent that. A list of ~40 fill-in-the-blank questions seems like it should do it... but then why hasn't anyone?

Comment: I believe that implementing threads (and the related constructs such as mutexes and conditions) without assembler inserts or compiler support will be extraordinarily difficult. Plauger, as I said, discusses many of the issues, and gets very close to what you are seeking for C89; it can probably do the same for C99, and most of C11 or C18 (with threads being the area that I think cannot be achieved without assembler support, which makes that part of the code compiler and/or O/S dependent). A lot depends on the range of hardware you expect to support, too. There are some esoteric CPUs out there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not following, are you refuting something I'm not saying? Yes mutexes, threads, fork, I/O, etc will require specifics about the system in question. I started the original question with that. But I've yet to see a reason that whole library couldn't be implemented on-top of a dozen or three well defined, simple primitive that are "simple" to implement in any environment in which the construct has meaning at all. newlib (if you haven't already; read that link from above) does that part way. My question is: does something prevent doing that the whole way? Your list doesn't?

Comment: I dunno — I've lost track of the discussion.  Ignore me; I'm going away.  (I don't think the differences between different processors will be handled by 40 questions — at least, not unless the answer to some of those questions involves writing the appropriate assembler.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Actually, I'm 100% fine with a need to write ASM (preferably as non-inline functions), provided the expected behavior of that ASM is well defined an can generally be done without support from the compiler developers. I suspect some of them would even be independent of the compiler.

Comment: Assembler notation in C code is compiler-dependent.